# How to save different file name from the android camera in java

Tags: java, android, file, camera, device

I have a very long java file that helps me implement a camera but how do I modify the saved jpg name be different everytime? I am fairly new to java and android. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!!

Also the reason that i am not using the built in camera is because I want to use a cookie cutter type cropping and I don't know how to load the images into my app...

```js
  final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallbackListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
      super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
      Toast.makeText(AndroidCameraApi.this, "Saved:" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      createCameraPreview();
    }
  };

 final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pic.jpg");
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. What have you done to try and change the file name?

Comment: If you don't know how does this piece of code work, why don't you read up the documentation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please look at this line of code:

```
final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/pic.jpg");
```

it sets the file name (pic.jpg). You can change to whatever you want here.

Comment: I reduced my code as it was alot. I saw this previously but was wondering not only how to change it but how to make it a different file name eachtime as this is hard coded. I did not see documentation on the site that i was on so maybe i should just use the android website docu?

Comment: This will definitely set a different file name for each shot:

final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pic" + System.currentTimeMillis () +".jpg");

Comment: Thank you so much. That has worked!